# Loading data from array in popup when country is clicked in React Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, array, react

I'm newbie and I have interactive web in react using leaflet library and now I need to load "title" data from array to a map. So when I click on some country, popup will show up with this data. Now it shows only `UNDEFINED` or when I delete that `.value`, it shows `[object, Object]`.

```
const onEachCountry = (country, layer, data) => {
    const countryName = country.properties.ADMIN;
    data = init_data
    const titleName = 
    data.map((datatit) => {
      return {
        label: datatit.title,
        value: datatit.title
      }
    })
    console.log(titleName)
    layer.bindPopup(countryName + " job adds are: " + titleName.value);
   

   
    layer.on({
      mouseover: highlightFeature,
      mouseout: resetHighlight,
      click: selectLayer
    })
  };
```

example of `init_data` array which I'm importing from another .js file, which is basically only this array, but pretty big.

```
const init_data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "This i need to appear when layer is clicked",
    source: "xy",
    company: "xy",
    country: "Czechia",
    continent: "Europe",
    date: "2021-01-01",
    field: "CS",
    description:
      "What is it about?..
    type: "Operate",
    partners: "UT",
    owner: "1",
    key: "1",
  },
  ...
```

Comment: I suppose `init_data` is an array with additional data for each country feature. To get the right element for certain country, there must be some unique id in country feature by which you can find the corresponding element in `init_data`. Then you can use the array method `.find` to retrieve the corresponding element, something like `var additData = init_data.find(function(data) {return(data.id == feature.properties.ID);});`

Answer (score 1):

The loading of a .json file from hard disk is an **asynchronous operation** and thus it needs to specify a callback function to execute after the file is loaded.
You could find more info in the following links:
[read local JSON file into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073151/read-local-json-file-into-variable),
[Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)